# Android code for file rename process

Tags: java, android, file, rename, file-rename

I need to rename a file name for a android application. I wrote the code inside onListItemClick() but it is not working. I didnt get any exception either. Here is the code. What is the error here ?

```
File oldFile = new File(path.get(position));
        String oldFileName=path.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, path.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String segments[]=oldFileName.split("/");
        String fileName=segments[segments.length-1];
        String newFileName=oldFileName.replace(fileName, "log_B.txt");
        File newFile=new File(newFileName);


    if(!oldFile.isDirectory()){

        System.out.println("File Name is:"+fileName);

        try{
            if(oldFile.renameTo(newFile)){
                System.out.println("File renamed successfull !");

            }else{
                System.out.println("File renamed operation failed");
            }


        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Exception :"+ex.getMessage());
        }

    }else{

        System.out.println("Folder Name is :"+fileName);

    }
```

Comment: Let's see the output you get.

Comment: I get "File renamed operation failed" and not get any exception. I tried to do this by giving path as "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()" too. But still get the same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have write permissions defined in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

The File.renameTo() method will fail under the following conditions:

- Write permission is required on the directories containing both the
  source and destination paths.
- Search permission is required for all parents of both paths.
- Both paths be on the same mount point. On Android, applications are
  most likely to hit this restriction when attempting to copy between
  internal storage and an SD card.

As described in the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)

Additionally, I would verify that the newFile path is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Can I change the file permission withing the code? Or else how to do that?

Comment: Generally speaking no. Unless your application has system level privileges. Your application only has write access to public directories such as the external SD storage, or it's internal directory. See: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: Oh thanks :) silly mistake, After I add  "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>" to Manifest file it works fine.

Comment: No problem, I'll update the question to better reflect your solution. Please remember to accept my answer if it solved your issue. All the best with your project :)